# How to change the tool tip duration format in Google Chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, datetime-format, pygooglechart

How can I format the tool-tip duration value to HH: MM format. Currently, I'm getting the value in total hours format. Like 1.50 hours but I want it in 1h 30m format.
In the below link the example for both formattings is already available but I can't see the difference in both the example:

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline#controlling-the-colors

Also, I want to show the total time duration of similar values across the row, is it possible?
Like if I have CSS Fundamental in two places in the first row then I want to show the duration of both the values.
Below is the code where its showing duration in HH: MM format

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load("current", {packages:["timeline"]});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {

    var container = document.getElementById('example5.1');
    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Room' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Name' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
    dataTable.addRows([
      [ 'Magnolia Room', 'Beginning JavaScript',       new Date(0,0,0,12,0,0),  new Date(0,0,0,13,30,0) ],
      [ 'Magnolia Room', 'Intermediate JavaScript',    new Date(0,0,0,14,0,0),  new Date(0,0,0,15,30,0) ],
      [ 'Magnolia Room', 'Advanced JavaScript',        new Date(0,0,0,16,0,0),  new Date(0,0,0,17,30,0) ],
      [ 'Willow Room',   'Beginning Google Charts',    new Date(0,0,0,12,30,0), new Date(0,0,0,14,0,0) ],
      [ 'Willow Room',   'Intermediate Google Charts', new Date(0,0,0,14,30,0), new Date(0,0,0,16,0,0) ],
      [ 'Willow Room',   'Advanced Google Charts',     new Date(0,0,0,16,30,0), new Date(0,0,0,18,0,0) ]]);

    var options = {
      timeline: { colorByRowLabel: true }
    };

    chart.draw(dataTable, options);
  }

</script>

<div id="example5.1" style="height: 100px;"></div>
```

Code which generates duration in 1.50 hours format:

```html
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load("current", {packages:["timeline"]});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
    
        var container = document.getElementById('example5.2');
        var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
        var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Room' });
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Name' });
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
        dataTable.addRows([
          [ 'Magnolia Room',  'CSS Fundamentals',    new Date(0,0,0,12,0,0),  new Date(0,0,0,14,0,0) ],
          [ 'Magnolia Room',  'Intro JavaScript',    new Date(0,0,0,14,30,0), new Date(0,0,0,16,0,0) ],
          [ 'Magnolia Room',  'Advanced JavaScript', new Date(0,0,0,16,30,0), new Date(0,0,0,19,0,0) ],
          [ 'Gladiolus Room', 'Intermediate Perl',   new Date(0,0,0,12,30,0), new Date(0,0,0,14,0,0) ],
          [ 'Gladiolus Room', 'Advanced Perl',       new Date(0,0,0,14,30,0), new Date(0,0,0,16,0,0) ],
          [ 'Gladiolus Room', 'Applied Perl',        new Date(0,0,0,16,30,0), new Date(0,0,0,18,0,0) ],
          [ 'Petunia Room',   'Google Charts',       new Date(0,0,0,12,30,0), new Date(0,0,0,14,0,0) ],
          [ 'Petunia Room',   'Closure',             new Date(0,0,0,14,30,0), new Date(0,0,0,16,0,0) ],
          [ 'Petunia Room',   'App Engine',          new Date(0,0,0,16,30,0), new Date(0,0,0,18,30,0) ]]);
    
        var options = {
          timeline: { singleColor: '#8d8' },
        };
    
        chart.draw(dataTable, options);
      }
    </script>
    
    <div id="example5.2" style="height: 150px;"></div>
```

Comment: @WhiteHat I have added the example code

Comment: so I changed the last example above to a working example and see the 1.50 hours format. but when I run the same code on my page, it shows the other format. not sure...

Comment: at times when I shorten the name it fixes itself (shows 4h 34m 14s instead of 4.57 hours ) and other times if the end timestamp exceeds 11 pm it reappears ..... whoever coded this shit at google should not be allowed to touch a keyboard ever again.

Answer (score 0):

you have to rewrite the tooltip ...

```
data.insertColumn(2, {type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', p: {html: true}});
var tooltip = '<div class="ggl-tooltip"><span>' +
    data.getValue(i, 1) + '</span></div><div class="ggl-tooltip"><span>' +
    data.getValue(i, 0) + '</span></div>';

  data.setValue(i, 2, tooltip);
}

chart.draw(data, {
  tooltip: {
    isHtml: true
  }
});
```